# Symfony insert database entries while foreach loop

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My problem is, that symfony only inserts the last entry in the foreach loop and not all entries.

In my example, only Test 2 will be inserted.

My code:
information: $_POST['title'] = Test, Test

$_POST['number'] = 1, 2

```
$titles = $_POST['title'] ?? [];
$numbers = $_POST['number'] ?? [];

    foreach ($titles as $key => $title) {
        $product->setNumber($numbers[$key]);
        dump($numbers[$key]);
        $product->setTitle($title);
        dump($title);
        $em->persist($product);
    }
    $em->flush();
```

Screenshot of my dump:

[Screenshot of dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euhD5.png)

Comment: It looks like you are reusing and saving/updating the same `$product` instance, you should create a new one in your foreach loop: `$product = new Product();`

Answer (score 0):

when you call

`$em->persist($product);` it will store an ID into the `$product` entity and store it as a record in DB

if you den change the title and store again, it will look at the `$product` entity and see "OH THERE IS AN ID, SO HE WANTS TO DO UPDATE" so `$em` stores the title for the ID that is set in `$product` on your first loop.